# Shallow nested routes in Phoenix framework

Tags: phoenix-framework

Looking at Phoenix, is there an equivalent to `shallow` routing similar to how rails accomplishes this?

This would allow you to reference `/posts/1` instead of `/users/2/posts/1`

e.g.,

`resources "/users", UserController do
  resources "/posts", PostController, shallow: true
end`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look like [`Phoenix.Router.resources/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4) supports a `:shallow` opt, but this would get the job done:

```
resources "/users", UserController do
  resources "/posts", PostController, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources "/posts", PostController, except: [:index, :new, :create], as: :user_post
```

Upon `mix phoenix.routes` amongst your other routes, you'll see:

```
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts      YourApp.PostController :index
user_post_path  GET     /users/:user_id/posts/new  YourApp.PostController :new
user_post_path  POST    /users/:user_id/posts      YourApp.PostController :create
user_post_path  GET     /posts/:id/edit            YourApp.PostController :edit
user_post_path  GET     /posts/:id                 YourApp.PostController :show
user_post_path  PATCH   /posts/:id                 YourApp.PostController :update
                PUT     /posts/:id                 YourApp.PostController :update
user_post_path  DELETE  /posts/:id                 YourApp.PostController :delete
```